# PHP 7 - references lost during array property traversal

Tags: php, arrays, reference

I want to find an array property's element, which is also an array and I want to append more members to it. I can append it, but somehow the references seem to be lost and all I'm left is a copy. The original array is unaffected. This is my code:

```
<?php

class CategoryTree
{
    var $tree;

    public function CategoryTree() {
        // First element of the array represents the name of the category, so to iterate children, we have to go from index 1
        $tree=$this->tree;
        $tree["root"] = array();
    }

    private function &getCategoryWithNameInSubtree($name, &$subTreeRoot) {

        if (count($subTreeRoot) == 0) return false; // There are no branches coming from this root

        // So, the subtree has some branches to traverse... 
        foreach ($subTreeRoot as $branchName => &$branch) {
            if ($branchName == $name) { // Search is over - this branch has the specified name
                return $subTreeRoot[$branchName]; 
            } else {
                $subTreeSearchResult = $this->getCategoryWithNameInSubtree($name, $branch);
                if($subTreeSearchResult) {
                    return $subTreeSearchResult;
                } else {
                    //If we have reached this, it means the name was not found in that branch
                }
            }

        }

        //We traversed all branches and no name was equal to the specified name
        return false;

    }

    public function &getCategoryWithName($name) {
        $tree=&$this->tree;
        return $this->getCategoryWithNameInSubtree("seconda", $tree);

    }
}


$c = new CategoryTree();

$c->tree=array("prima" => array("prima-prima" => [], "prima-seconda" => [], "prima-terza" => []),
               "seconda" => array("seconda-prima" => [], "seconda-seconda" => [], "seconda-terza" => []),
               "terza" => array("terza-prima" => [], "terza-seconda" => [], "terza-terza" => []),
              );


$seconda=$c->getCategoryWithName("seconda");
$seconda[] = "added";
print "cat is: <pre>"; print_r($seconda); print "</pre>";

print "ct is: <pre>"; print_r($c); print "</pre>";
```

I want the change to "seconda" to persist in the original property $c->tree, but they are not. The references are lost somewhere. Do you know how is this properly set up? I use a recursion off course, for traversal, so that might be a problem, but I highly doubt it. Can you help out? Thanks anyway. This would clear out my confusion about PHP references.

Comment: Are you really still running PHP 4?

Comment: No. PHP 7. Is the version.

Comment: @MarkBaker FYI, if I remove the "&" characters, the problem remains. What is your point, I don't understand?

Comment: You do then realise that the code you've posted was written for PHP 4, it should generate a few warnings telling you this... and there have been a few changes in the way PHP handles references since then

Comment: Well help me get/set the value of a property as an array- PHP 7 style then, seeing that you know a lot. Instead of realizing the code was written for this or that version of PHP. Thanks.

Comment: Personally, if it was my code, I'd rewrite it completely for PHP7.... which I don't have the time to do

Comment: @MarkBaker absolutely no suggestions on improving the code?

Comment: Yes! My suggestion to improve it is to rewrite it as PHP7 code, not to try sticking a band-aid on it

Comment: I think this is wrong thinking from @MarkBaker. There is no way to avoid using references here, if I need to use recursion. And I have to use recursion here, to traverse all children, and children of children etc.

Comment: Well perhaps for all my wrong thinking about rewriting it for PHP7... why not consider eliminating the PHP4-style `&getCategoryWithNameInSubtree` and replace it instead with `return &$subTreeSearchResult;`, etc.

Comment: Maybe because that causes a clean Fatal error in PHP 7? :) LOL, thanks for the suggestion though, I want to clear things up a bit here, it does look messy, to be honest :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add reference symbol before element that should be referenced

```
$seconda = &$c->getCategoryWithName("seconda");
           ^ here
```

Just stick to simple rule:

```
$arr = Array();
$copy = $arr; // copy
$reference = &$arr; // reference
```

This is how references works with functions/classes

```
public function getArray() // always copy
$arr = $class->getArray() // copy
$arr = &$class->getArray() // copy

public function &getArray() // returns reference
$arr = $class->getArray() // copy
$arr = &$class->getArray() // reference
```

Comment: The problem is not this. The problem is the propagation of values through the functions. The references seem to become lost there. I don't know where to put the ampersand signs.

Comment: It does. But, the simple rule
$arr = Array();
$copy = $arr; // copy
$reference = &$arr; // reference
does not apply without some other ampersands put throughout the code. My point is that what you wrote is not enough.

Comment: `My point is that what you wrote is not enough` so what do you need? it's working exactly as you wanted https://3v4l.org/9fF0c

Comment: Ok, now I understand. So I need to put the & both in the declaration and in the call in order for it to work as expected?